# How can I create a list of X richest bitcoin addresses?

Tags: blockchain, balance, python

I have looked around, but I can't find the code related directly to my question. I want to create a list in any format that contains the all accounts with balance over 0 for example. Thanks ahead for any help.

Comment: Something like [this](http://bitcoinrichlist.com/top100)? From the faq it looks like they used [this](https://github.com/znort987/blockparser) code. Maybe you can do something with that. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Have an up-to-date blockchain in `~/.bitcoin`
2. Download and compile [blockparser](https://github.com/znort987/blockparser).
3. Run `./parser allBalances >allBalances.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If you have abe-bitcoin installed you can run an sql query on the database.

Or use:

https://bitinfocharts.com/top-100-richest-bitcoin-addresses.html